# Jboss 7 OSGI runlevel

Tags: java, osgi, jboss7.x, runlevel

is there a proper way to define the start level of osgi bundles on JBoss 7.1 application server, like on equinox configuration?

thanks!!!

Comment: Depends how you deploy your bundles to JBoss?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you should first determine what bundle or code inside of your server actually installs your bundles. This bundle, often referred to as the "management agent" should then probably also be made responsible for setting the correct start level for these bundles. OSGi defines a "StartLevel" service (described in chapter 8 of the specification) that, amongst other things, allows you to set the start level for bundles by either using:

```
setInitialBundleStartLevel(int) // sets the start level for
                                   all bundles installed afterwards
```

or:

```
setBundleStartLevel(Bundle, int) // sets the start level for a
                                    specific bundle
```

Of course, it could well be that JBoss already provides a mechanism that does exactly this, but at least this should give you a starting point.